# A good approximation algorithm for the maximum weight perfect match in non-bipartite graphs?

Tags: php, javascript, algorithm, math, graph

Drake and Hougardy find a simple approximation algorithm for the maximum weighted matching problem. I think my understanding of academic papers is above my capabilities so I'm looking for an easy implementation preferable in php, c, javascript?

Comment: The Drake-Hougardy algorithm is an approximation; it gives a solution that is good but perhaps not the best. Do you want an explanation of both algorithms?

Comment: @epitaph:  The subject line asks for "minimum weight perfect match", but [the Drake-Hougardy algorithm](http://www.or.uni-bonn.de/~hougardy/paper/ImprovedMatching.pdf) only promises a maximum weight approximation.  Are you able to work-around for matchings that are not perfect/complete?  One can redefine the objective of minimum weight matching to maximum weight matching if the size of the matching is predetermined, however I saw nothing in their paper about this (or about forcing perfect matchings, as conceivably the maximum matching is attained without being perfect).

Comment: @epitaph:  You are the expert about what you want/need; I'm just trying to figure out how/if I can help.  The Drake-Hougardy algorithm deals with a linear time approximation to the maximum weight matching problem. What other algorithm are you including in "both"?

Comment: @epitaph:  Okay, I think what Beta meant was the earlier and later papers/algorithms proposed by Drake and Hougardy.  The first one is much simpler and guarenteed to find (in linear time) a matching with at least half the weight of the maximum weight matching, and the second one is more complicated but gives results that provide nearly 2/3rds of the maximum (still in linear time).  I'll write up the first one.  I still have a quibble about the word "perfect" in your subject line, but I will tackle it in the Anwser as well, so I can define terms.

Comment: Perhaps I'm speaking out of turn, but is this a good candidate for http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Tass: I think epitaph has sufficiently related the question to a software implementation issue to post here.  Of course the line is not a sharp one, and there's also the Theoretic CS board, but I think the Answer as requested needs to address data representation.

Comment: Initially I wanted to say something like, "This is a real rookie question.  We're not even going to dignify it with a response."  (In reality I have no idea what you're all even talking about.)  ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Problem Definition and References**

Given a simple graph (undirected, no self-edges, no multi-edges) a **matching**
is a subset of edges such that no two of them are incident to the same vertex.

A **perfect** matching is one in which all vertices are incident to an edge of
the matching, something not possible if there are an odd number of vertices.
More generally we can ask for a maximum matching (largest possible number of
edges in a matching) or for a maximal matching (a matching to which no more
edges can be added).

If positive real "weights" are assigned to the edges, we can generalize the
problem to ask for a **maximum-weighted matching**, one that maximizes the
sum of edges' weights.  The exact maximum-weighted matching problem can be
solved in O(nm log(n)) time, where n is the number of vertices and m the
number of edges.

Note that a maximum-weighted matching need not be a perfect matching.  For
example:

```
*--1--*--3--*--1--*
```

has only one perfect matching, whose total weight is 2, and a maximum
weighted matching with total weight 3.

Discussion and further references for exact and approximate solutions of
these, and of the minimum-weighted perfect matching problem, may be found
in these papers:

["A Simple Approximation Algorithm for the Weighted Matching Problem"](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~athorsen/research/matchings/papers/Drake2002-SimpleApproxAlg.pdf)
Drake, Doratha E. and Hougardy, Stefan (2002)

[Implementation of O(nm log n) Weighted Matchings The Power of Data Structures](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/WAE00.ps.gz)
Melhorn, Kurt and Schäfer, Guido (2000)

[Computing Minimum-Weight Perfect Matchings](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~wcook/papers/match_ijoc.pdf)
Cook, William and Rohe, André (1997)

[Approximating Maximum Weight Matching in Near-linear Time](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~duanran/ApproxMWM.pdf)
Duan, Ran and Pettie, Seth (2010)

**Drake and Hougardy's Simple Approximation Algorithm**

The first approximation algorithm of Drake-Hougardy uses the idea
of growing paths using the locally heaviest edge at each vertex met.  It
has a "performance ratio" of 1/2 like the greedy algorithm, but linear
time complexity in the number of edges (the greedy algorithm uses
a globally heaviest edge and incurs greater time complexity to find that).

The main implementation task is to identify data structures that support
the steps of their algorithm efficiently.

The idea of the PathGrowing algorithm:

```
Given: a simple undirected graph G with weighted edges

(0) Define two sets of edges L and R, initially empty.
(1) While the set of edges of G is not empty, do:
(2)    Choose arbitrary vertex v to which an edge is incident.
(3)    While v has incident edges, do:
(4)        Choose heaviest edge {u,v} incident to v.
(5)        Add edge {u,v} to L or R in alternating fashion.
(6)        Remove vertex v (and its incident edges) from G.
(7)        Let u take the role of v.
(8)    Repeat 3.
(9) Repeat 1.

Return L or R, whichever has the greater total weight.
```

**Data structures to represent the graph and the output**

As a "set" is not in any immediate sense a data structure of C, we
need to decide what kinds of container for edges and vertices will
suit this algorithm.  The critical operations are removing vertices
and incident edges in a way that allows us to find if any edges are
left and to compare weights of the remaining edges incident to a
given vertex.

The edges need to be searchable, but only to see if any is still left.
One thinks first of a simple linked list of edges, without any special
ordering.  But this list also needs to be maintained through essentially
random deletions.  This suggests a doubly-linked list (back links as
well as forward at each node), so that deletion of an edge may be done
by fixing up the links to skip over any "removed" node.  Edge weights
can also be stored in this same structure.

Further we need the ability to scan all (remaining) edges incident to
a given vertex.  We can do this by creating a linked list for each vertex
of (pointers to) incident edges.  I will assume that the vertices have
been preprocessed to ordinal values that can be used as an index into
an array of pointers to these linked lists.

Finally we need to represent the edge sets L and R, one of which is to
be returned as the approximate maximum matching.  Our requirements
are to be able to add edges to either set, and to be able to total the
edge weights for both of them.  Linked lists with dynamically allocated
nodes can serve this purpose, perhaps storing pointers to the edge nodes
in the original doubly-linked lists as the weight attribute will still
persist there even after an edge becomes "removed" by link manipulation.

Such linked and doubly-linked lists can be created in time proportional
to the number of edges, since the doubly-linked list entries may be
allocated to vertex-specific links on input.  With such a design in
mind we can analyze the effort required by each step of the algorithm.

(to be continued)

Comment: @epitaph:  Incident is the relation of edge to vertex when the vertex is one of the two endpoints of the edge.  (The degree of a vertex is the count of edges incident to it.)  In a weighted graph each edge is assigned a numeric "weight".  So "heaviest edge" just means the edge with the greatest "weight".

Comment: @epitaph:  In line (7) we are going to assign the other endpoint u of the heaviest edge to play the role of v in the next repeat of (3).  As we have removed the edges incident to the old v, we will be looking for the heaviest edge "remaining" incident to u in the next loop.  If there are none left, then the loop (3) ends; we've reached a dead-end on the current path.  Then a new outer loop (1) begins, starting from some remaining edge (until no more edges are left).

Comment: @epitaph: Yes, the graph picture is something like that.  However if you label the far left and far right vertices both as A, it suggests that you mean to identify them, making the whole graph a triangle.  This would mess up what I said about a perfect matching for my example (with four vertices along a simple path).  But the maximum weighted matching would still be just the one edge in your "triangle".