# Find point correspondence between two point sets minimizing the sum of distance of all matches

Tags: algorithm, geometry

My question is, given two point sets A and B, element size of A is no more than that of B, is there any efficient way to find the corresponding point in B for each point in A, such that the sum of distance of all matches is minimal? Each point in B can be used no more than once.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) for weighted bipartite matching.

For each edge between an element of A and an element of B, let the weight of that edge be the distance between them. Then, run the Hungarian Algorithm minimizing the total sum of the weights.

The total run time is O(|A|^3).

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! But I guess it may be too slow for my data (about 20000 points in my case). Is there any approximate solution? Thanks!

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203894/a-good-approximation-algorithm-for-the-maximum-weight-perfect-match-in-non-bipar) to be helpful.

Comment: Note that sometimes the algorithms might be talking about maximum weight matchings, but that is fine, because to find the minimum weight matching, let W be the maximum of all edge weights in your graph, and take new edge weights to be W-old edge weights. Find the maximum weight matching with the new weights, and at the end, if you found a matching of size M, the minimum weight matching with your original edge weights is M*W-result.

Comment: Thanks! But I guess maximum weight matching cannot guarantee each points in A can be matched, is that correct?

Comment: Nope, all approximate algorithms will guarantee that every point in A will be matched. It is approximate because it cannot guarantee you will get the best matching, so there might be a better matching where the sum of distances is smaller.